# How to set tabs according specific grids in bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I'll be glad if you can help me on a specific issue for which I haven't find
any solution for that.

I have to make a web page in bootstrap which includes horizontal tabs.
The issue is that I need that The first tab will start from the
2nd grid and beyond as seen below:

[image]

I tried with my code but nothing works as expected in the image above:

```css
.nav-tabs-colors {
  background-color: #ececef;
}

.edit-app-tabs {
  background-color:#ececef;
}

#edit-app-tab {
  background-color:#ececef;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


    <div class="tabbable edit-app-tabs">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-colors">
            <div class="col-lg-offset-1"><li role="presentation"></li></div>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a></li>
            <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#edit-app-tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab5</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab6</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab7</a></li>
            <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab8</a></li>
        </ul>
     <div class="tab-content">
      <div id="edit-app-tab" class="tab-pane fade in active">
       <div class="row">
        <h3>Content Content Content</h3>
       </div>
      </div>
        </div>
    <div>
```

Can you please show me how to exact fit the tabs according to specific grid ?

Thanks in Advance for your help!

EVH671

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could for instance put your tabs into a divider with col-md-offset-1 class

```css
.nav-tabs-colors {
  background-color: #ececef;
}
.edit-app-tabs {
  background-color: #ececef;
}
#edit-app-tab {
  background-color: #ececef;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="tabbable edit-app-tabs">
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-colors col-md-offset-1">
    <div class="">
      <li role="presentation"></li>
    </div>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab1</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#edit-app-tab" data-toggle="tab">Tab2</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab3</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab4</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab5</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab6</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab7</a>
    </li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#" data-toggle="tab">Tab8</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div id="edit-app-tab" class="tab-pane fade in active">
      <div class="row">
        <h3>Content Content Content</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div>
```

More on grids: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid
Bare in mind that this offset's the div by 1 column in medum viewport and up.
and it'd be wise to have your whole layout structured properly with containers, rows and columns.